# UPDATE only provided fields in MySQL table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a user table with and `id` field and 10 other fields storing user details of various types that the user can change via various web forms. I want to have a PHP script that gets POSTed changed values for some subset of these fields, and UPDATEs only those fields that are received in the POST data. I'm finding this surprisingly difficult to do in a way that doesn't suck. We use mysqli for all database interaction in the rest of this application so mysqli-based solutions are strongly preferred.

The options I've considered and dismissed so far:

1) Run a separate `UPDATE` query for every field provided in the POST data - *yuck, I don't want to hit the database up to 10 times for something that could be done in one query.*

2) Have a dictionary mapping field names to the fields' data types, and iteratively construct the query by looping through the provided fields, checking whether they are text fields or not, calling `mysqli_real_escape_string` on the string fields and otherwise sanitizing the others (e.g. by type checking or `sprintf` with '%i' placeholders). - *Yuck! I could probably safely do things this way if I was careful, but I don't want to make a habit of using this kind of approach because if I'm careless I'll leave myself open to SQL injection. Parameterized queries don't give me the potential to screw up dangerously, but this approach does. My ideal is to never concatenate any data into an SQL query manually and always rely upon parameterized queries; the database libraries of other languages, like Python, let me easily do this.*

3) Use a parameterized query - this is my ideal for everything, since as long as I insert all externally-provided data into my query via the `bind_param` method of a mysqli statement object, I'm immune to SQL injection and don't have to worry about sanitization, but using parameterized queries seems to be impossible here. The trouble is that `bind_param` requires that the data be passed as variables, since all arguments after the first are passed by reference. I can reasonably elegantly iteratively construct a query with `?` placeholders, and while I'm at it construct the string of types that gets passed as the first argument to `bind_param` (`'ssiddsi'` etc.), but then there's no way I can see to choose at runtime which of my 10 fields I pass to `bind_params` (unless I have a `switch` statement with 10^2 cases).

Is there some PHP language construct I'm missing (something similar to array unpacking) that will allow me to choose at runtime which variables to pass as arguments to `bind_param`? Or is there some other approach I haven't considered that will let me solve this simple problem cleanly and safely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily combine 2 and 3 by means of my [SafeMySQL library](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql/blob/master/safemysql.class.php).
The code will look like

```
$allowed = array('title','url','body','rating','term','type');
$data    = $db->filterArray($_POST,$allowed);
$sql     = "UPDATE table SET ?u WHERE id=?i";
$db->query($sql, $data, $_POST['id']);
```

note that `$allowed` array doesn't make all these fields necessarily updated - it just filters POST fields out. So, even $_POST with only id and url would be correctly updated.

Nevertheless, using prepared statements, although toilsome, also quite possible.

Comment: I assume `$db` here is a custom class of db-related utility functions that you suggest I make? What's the `query()` method going to do with the parameters you're passing it here? Presumably it will at least need to be passed the types of the parameters in `$data`, in addition to the arguments you're already passing it, so that it knows how to go about sanitizing them?

Comment: You don't actually need different types with UPDATE and mysql - all the data will be happily inserted as strings.

Comment: The example above is actually a working code using my [safemysql class](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql/blob/master/safemysql.class.php) if you interested to look. It is using scaring concatenation though

Comment: 2) Cool, I'll give your class a look. 1) Wait, so you're saying that (for example) one can just do stuff like `"INSERT INTO someTable (someField) VALUES ('" . mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['someField']) . "')"` and MySQL will handle it properly, despite the quotes, even if `someField` is a non-string data type? That's useful to know and should simplify any ugly manual sanitization I might ever have to do.

Comment: Yes, mysql is loosely typed (unless in STRICT mode though), as well as PHP. The same goes for prepared statements too - you can bind all the parameters in a loop using `'s'` type for them all.

Comment: Thanks. I have a clearer idea of how I could do what I need, now. I may well suggest to my boss that we use your database class; it seems to offer the benefits of mysqli parameterized queries (impossible to create an injection vulnerability via a silly programming slip; more readable code than concatting and using `mysqli_real_escape_string` all over the place) without the latter's irritating bullshit (like having to copy every argument into a variable before passing to `bind_param` since they are passed by reference). The `'?a'` and `'?u'` placeholders also look handy.

Comment: Thanks, you've got everything right with it :)  though it is even more powerful if you look closer. Feel free to ask on any issues or use cases, I've got a ton of them, all solved :)

Answer (score -2):

See the code below

```
public function update($data, $table, $where) {
    $data_str = '' ;
    foreach ($data as $column => $value) {
        //append comma each time after first item
        if (!empty($data_str)) $data_str .= ', ' ;
        $data_str .= "$column = $value" ;
    }
    $sql = "UPDATE $table SET $data_str WHERE $where";
    mysqli_query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());
    return true;
}
```

$data is an array, in your case it's $_POST.

If you want to be more specific about the data to be saved from $_POST array, you can define an array of allowed columns. For example,

```
$allowed = array('id', 'username', 'email', 'password');
```

By doing this, you can filter your $_POST array and pass it to update() function.

Comment: This code is prone to SQL injection. Besides, it will never work.